# Custom stripe payment in asp.net mvc 5 with optional parameter in the action controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stripe-payments

Am new to stripe asp.net mvc payment

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/Purchase")]
public ActionResult Purchase(string  stripeEmail, string stripeToken,int amount, Customer customer)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var stripecustomers = new StripeCustomerService();
        var charges = new StripeChargeService();


        Customer c = new Customer
        {
            FirstName  = customer.FirstName,
            LastName = customer.LastName,
            Email = customer.Email,
            Phone = customer.Phone,
            Address = customer.Address,
            City  = customer.City,
            State = customer.State,
            PostalCode = customer.PostalCode,
            Country = customer.Country
        };
        Order o = new Order
        {
            OrderDate = DateTime.Now,
            DeliveryDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5),
            CID = c.CID
        };

        db.Customers.Add(c);
        db.Orders.Add(o);

        foreach (var i in db.ShoppingCartDatas.ToList<ShoppingCartData>())
        {
            db.Order_Products.Add(new Order_Products
            {
                OrderID = o.OrderID,
                PID = i.PID,
                Qty = i.Quantity,
                TotalSale = i.Quantity * i.UnitPrice
            });
            db.ShoppingCartDatas.Remove(i);
        }

        db.SaveChanges();

        var stripecustomer = stripecustomers.Create(new StripeCustomerCreateOptions {
            Email = stripeEmail,
            SourceToken = stripeToken
        });


        var charge = charges.Create(new StripeChargeCreateOptions {
            // Amount 500 equals to $5.00 
            Amount = amount,
            Description = "Test Site",
            Currency = "usd",
            CustomerId = stripecustomer.Id
        });
        double adjamt = amount;
        adjamt = adjamt/100;
        ViewBag.Amount = adjamt;
        return View();

    }

    return View(customer);
}
```

and my Payment view

```
<h2>Purchase</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Purchase", "Checkout", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.State, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.State, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PostalCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PostalCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PostalCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Country, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Country, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Country, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <p>Total: @String.Format("{0:c}", ViewBag.CartTotalPrice)</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                @{
                    decimal sum = ViewBag.CartTotalPrice;
                    decimal amount = sum * 100;
                    int adjamt = (int)amount;
                }
                <script src="//checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js"
                        class="stripe-button"
                        data-key="pk_test_key"
                        data-locale="auto"
                        data-description="test Site"
                        data-amount=@adjamt>
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Stripe capture the payment, on clicking the pay button on stripe payment, i will get the following error on postback.

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'amount' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Purchase(System.String, System.String, Int32, AllPlus.Models.Customer)' in 'AllPlus.Controllers.CheckoutController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

Comment: Check if `int amount` parameter in `Purchase` controller has null value. The error explicitly said that.

Comment: Your not sending any value for `amount` so its `null` - hence the error (you do not have any form controls for `amount` nor do you have any route values for it in your `BeginForm()`)

Comment: you can get an idea from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65391324/how-to-integrate-stripe-payment-step-by-step-using-custom-form-in-asp-net-mvc/65391325#65391325