# How to integrate stripe payment with custom form in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stripe-payments, 3d-secure

How do I use custom stripe form and then integration with 3D Security options using ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: While it's OK to ask and answer your own question, you need to make the question into a legitimate question. Please add some more details and context about what you're doing. Pretend you are a person with an actual problem asking this question.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, can you please give me an example for this, as I am never asked and answer my own question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]
Custom Form Design using Razor/ Html

```
 <div class="campagin_start content" style="max-width:100%">
           <div class="cell example example2" id="">
                <form>
                   <div class="row">
                       <div class="field">
                             <div id="example2-card-number" class="input empty"></div>
                                <label for="example2-card-number" data-tid="elements_examples.form.card_number_label">Card number</label>
                                    <div class="baseline"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="field half-width">
                                    <div id="example2-card-expiry" class="input empty"></div>
                                    <label for="example2-card-expiry" data-tid="elements_examples.form.card_expiry_label">Expiration</label>
                                    <div class="baseline"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="field half-width">
                                    <div id="example2-card-cvc" class="input empty"></div>
                                    <label for="example2-card-cvc" data-tid="elements_examples.form.card_cvc_label">CVC</label>
                                    <div class="baseline"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                         
                            <button id="card-button">@WebResources.Donate $@Model.budget</button>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-border mt-10" style="display: none;margin-top: 10px;margin-left: 15px;" id="canceltran"> Cancel</a>
                        </form>
                       
                        <p id="payment-result"><!-- we'll pass the response from the server here --></p>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

***Script***

```
var stripe = Stripe('@ViewBag.StripePublishKey');
    var elementStyles = {
        base: {
            color: '#32325D',
            fontWeight: 500,
            fontFamily: 'Source Code Pro, Consolas, Menlo, monospace',
            fontSize: '16px',
            fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',

            '::placeholder': {
                color: '#CFD7DF',
            },
            ':-webkit-autofill': {
                color: '#e39f48',
            },
        },
        invalid: {
            color: '#E25950',

            '::placeholder': {
                color: '#FFCCA5',
            },
        },
    };

    var elementClasses = {
        focus: 'focused',
        empty: 'empty',
        invalid: 'invalid',
    };
    var elements = stripe.elements({
        fonts: [
            {
                cssSrc: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro',
            },
        ],
        // Stripe's examples are localized to specific languages, but if
        // you wish to have Elements automatically detect your user's locale,
        // use `locale: 'auto'` instead.
        locale: window.__exampleLocale
    });
    var Id = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Id)); // Get Id From Model
    var cardNumber = elements.create('cardNumber', {
            showIcon: true,
            style: elementStyles,
            classes: elementClasses,
        });
        cardNumber.mount('#example2-card-number');
    
        var cardExpiry = elements.create('cardExpiry', {
            style: elementStyles,
            classes: elementClasses,
        });
        cardExpiry.mount('#example2-card-expiry');
    
        var cardCvc = elements.create('cardCvc', {
            style: elementStyles,
            classes: elementClasses,
        });
        cardCvc.mount('#example2-card-cvc');
    var formClass = '.example2';
    var example = document.querySelector(formClass);
    var form = example.querySelector('form');
    var resultContainer = document.getElementById('payment-result');

    // Payment Button Handle

     form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        $('#AjaxLoader').show();
        event.preventDefault();
        resultContainer.textContent = "";
        stripe.createPaymentMethod({
            type: 'card',
            card: cardNumber,
        }).then(handlePaymentMethodResult);
    });

    function handlePaymentMethodResult(result) {
        if (result.error) {
            $('#AjaxLoader').hide();
            $("#canceltran").show(); 
            // An error happened when collecting card details, show it in the payment form
            resultContainer.textContent = result.error.message;
        } else {
            // Otherwise send paymentMethod.id to your server 
            fetch('/cart/pay', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify({ PaymentMethodId: result.paymentMethod.id, Id: Id}) 
            }).then(function (result) {
                return result.json();
            }).then(handleServerResponse);

        }
    }

    function handleServerResponse(responseJson) {
        if (responseJson.error) {
            // An error happened when charging the card, show it in the payment form
            resultContainer.textContent = responseJson.error;
            $('#AjaxLoader').hide();
            $("#canceltran").show();
        } else if (responseJson.requiresAction) {

            // Use Stripe.js to handle required card action
            stripe.handleCardAction(
                responseJson.clientSecret
            ).then(function (result) {

                if (result.error) {
                   
                    $('#AjaxLoader').hide();
                    resultContainer.textContent = result.error.message;
                    $("#canceltran").show();
                    // Show `result.error.message` in payment form
                } else {
                    // The card action has been handled
                    // The PaymentIntent can be confirmed again on the server
                    fetch('/cart/pay', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                        body: JSON.stringify({ PaymentIntentId: result.paymentIntent.id, Id:Id })
                    }).then(function (confirmResult) {
                        return confirmResult.json();
                    }).then(handleServerResponse);
                    $('#AjaxLoader').hide();
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            // Show a success message or Required action
            
          }
    }
```

***Controller*** -In Constructor, you have to use your Stripe Credentials

```
    public class CartController : ControllerBase
    {
        public CartController()
        {
            StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = YOUR API KEY; // Replace your API KEY here
        }
        string stripePublishKey = YOUR PUBLISHER KEY; // Replace your PUBLISHER KEY here
    
        private class StripeDataReq
        {
            public string PaymentMethodId { get; set; }
            public string PaymentIntentId { get; set; }
            public string Id { get; set; }
        }
    
        public async Task<ActionResult> Pay(StripeDataReq stripeDataReq)
        {
            // From Id you can get the value 
            var cart = await Cart.Table.LookupAsync(stripeDataReq.Id);
            // We set amount (amout*100) because here amount consider in cent (100 cent charge $1) so 
            var amount = cart.Budget * 100;
            var email = ""; // Set Email Id for payment Receiver
    
            var service = new PaymentIntentService();
            PaymentIntent paymentIntent = null;
            try
            {
                if (stripeDataReq.PaymentMethodId != null)
                {
                    // Create the PaymentIntent
                    var options = new PaymentIntentCreateOptions
                    {
                        Description = cart.Desc,
                        PaymentMethod = stripeDataReq.PaymentMethodId,
                        //Shipping is not nessasery for every region this is useful for an Indian Standard 
                        //Shipping = new ChargeShippingOptions
                        //{
                        //    Name = giver.Name,
                        //    Address = new AddressOptions
                        //    {
                        //        Line1 = "510 Townsend St",
                        //        PostalCode = "98140",
                        //        City = "San Francisco",
                        //        State = "CA",
                        //        Country = "US",
                        //    },
                        //},
    
                        ReceiptEmail = email,
                        Amount = amount,
                        Currency = "usd",
                        Confirm = true,
                        //ErrorOnRequiresAction = true,
                        ConfirmationMethod = "manual",
                    };
    
                    paymentIntent = service.Create(options);
                }
                if (stripeDataReq.PaymentIntentId != null)
                {
                    var confirmOptions = new PaymentIntentConfirmOptions { };
                    paymentIntent = service.Confirm(
                        stripeDataReq.PaymentIntentId,
                        confirmOptions
                    );
                }
            }
    
            // StripeException handle all types of failure error and then return the message into FE 
            catch (StripeException e)
            {
    
                return Json(new { error = e.StripeError.Message });
            }
            TempData["Id"] = stripeDataReq.Id;
            return await generatePaymentResponse(paymentIntent);
        }
    
    
    
        //For 3D secure card 
        private async Task<ActionResult> generatePaymentResponse(PaymentIntent intent)
        {
            var CartId = TempData["Id"];
    
            if (intent.Status.ToString().ToLower() == "succeeded")
            {
                // Handle post-payment fulfillment
                return Json(new { success = true });
    
            }
            // requires_action means 3d secure card required more authentications for payment
            else if (intent.Status == "requires_action")
            {
                // Tell the client to handle the action
                return Json(new
                {
                    requiresAction = true,
                    clientSecret = intent.ClientSecret
                });
            }
            else
            {
    
                // Any other status would be unexpected, so error
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid PaymentIntent status");
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Here is my working code with custom form integration using stripe payment, hope this post will help many developers