# Stripe subscription with 3D secure is incomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

For cards that do not require 3D security, it works flawlessly. But for those that require them, it gets stuck at `incomplete` status.
My implementation is very simple. The `frontend` collects the card info and makes a request to stripe's `API` to get the `token` and to create the `payment_method`.

```js
async submitForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  try {
    const { token } = await this.stripe.createToken(this.card);
    const { paymentMethod } = await this.stripe.createPaymentMethod({
      type: 'card',
      card: this.card,
    });

    this.stripeTokenHandler(token.id, paymentMethod.id); // handles submission to backend
  } catch (e) {
    this.cardErrorsTarget.textContent = e.error.message;
  }
}
```

The backend part is written in `rails`.

```rb
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
  source: params[:stripe_token],
  plan: plan_id,
  # address of the customer
)

# Creating the setup intent
intent = Stripe::PaymentIntent.create(
  amount: some_amount,
  customer: customer.id,
  payment_method_types: ["card"],
)

# After that I need to confirm the intent
confirm_intent = Stripe::PaymentIntent.confirm(intent.id, {
  payment_method: params[:pm_token],
  return_url: app_confirm_subscription_url # After 3D secure, it redirects to this URL
})
```

After the redirection,

```rb
def show
  intent = Stripe::PaymentIntent.retrieve(params[:payment_intent]) # stripe adds the payment_intent params
  
  raise intent
end
```

By raising the `intent`, I see that

```json
{
  paid: true,
  status: "succeeded",
  result: "authenticated",
  // more data
}
```

But when I go to Stripe's dashboard, it shows that the subscription is incomplete. These are the `events` in descending order.

```
The payment pi_1I6AVKCYHrwDIsnfiGm7bWUM for $29.00 USD has succeeded

example@example.com was charged $29.00 USD

The payment pi_1I6AVKCYHrwDIsnfiGm7bWUM for $29.00 USD requires you to take action in order to complete the payment

A new payment pi_1I6AVKCYHrwDIsnfiGm7bWUM for $29.00 USD was created

example@example.com attempted to subscribe to price_1I5vshCYHrwDIsnf981UpZEc

example@example.com added a new Visa ending in 3220

A card payment method ending in 3220 was attached to customer cus_IhZezT431x2G7Z

A draft invoice for $29.00 USD to example@example.com was finalized

A draft invoice was created

example@example.com is a new customer
```

**PS**: The card that I used is 4000 0000 0000 3220, which requires 3D security. If I use the 4242 4242 4242 4242, it works without any problems.

Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: get an idea from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65391324/how-to-integrate-stripe-payment-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Will look into it and let I'll let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a standalone PaymentIntent and using it to drive subscription creation is in this case the wrong integration. If we make reference to the guide for starting a fixed price subscription using Elements [1], the major steps are as follows:

1. Create a Customer
2. Collect the card information using a card element using `createPaymentMethod` from Stripe.js
3. Start the subscription by, a) attaching the payment method to the customer b) setting the payment method as the invoice settings, default payment method, c) creating the subscription
4. Handle authentication [2]

The key difference here is step 4. When you start a subscription, a PaymentIntent is created automatically under the hood and associated with the first invoice of the subscription. This is the PaymentIntent that should be used in conjunction with `confirmCardPayment` in the client using Stripe.js and the PaymentIntent's client secret [2]. It can be accessed by checking the `latest_invoice.payment_intent.status`  of the subscription after it is created i.e. after the first payment attempt.

There are quite a few other steps to handle for example when payment fails but the guide goes into details about the possible flows that you will encounter.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/fixed-price

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/fixed-price#manage-payment-authentication