# Unable to create active subscription (recurring) with Stripe 3D Secure, react native

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, stripe-payments

I am unable to create an active subscription with Stripe 3D secure using react-native frontend, node backend. The subscription has been created fine and is active for non 3D Secure Stripe payments. For 3D secure, the payment is varified and updated on payment dashboard, but the subscription is not being updated to be active at all.

Screenshots of the subscription (recurring):
[image: Screenshots of the subscription (recurring)]

Screenshot of the payment:
[image: Screenshot of the payment]

I have followed the workflow of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65575493/stripe-subscription-with-3d-secure-is-incomplete) stackoverflow answer, but it still does not work.

Frontend Code:

```
  const createSubscription = async () => {
    try {
      if (!cardFormData?.complete) {
        alert('Please input your card data!');
        setSaving(false);
        return;
      }

      const {firstName, lastName} = userData;
      const name = `${firstName} ${lastName}`;

      const billing_details = {
        email,
        name,
        description: name,
      };

      // making payment method
      const paymentMethod = await createPaymentMethod({
        paymentMethodType: 'Card',
        card: cardFormData,
        billing_details,
      });

      const body = JSON.stringify({
        paymentMethod: paymentMethod?.paymentMethod?.id,
        name,
        email,
      });

      console.log('going to make the api call');

      // call the backend to create subscription / customer / client secret
      const response = await fetch(`${APIURL}/pay/makePayment`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body,
      });

      const respJson = await response?.json();
      const {
        clientSecret,
        error: apiError,
        customerId,
        subscriptionId,
        subscriptionPaymentMethod,
        subscriptionStart,
        subscriptionEnd,
      } = respJson;

      if (apiError) {
        alert(`Payment Error 1 ` + apiError);
        setSaving(false);
      } else {
        // confirm the payment by the user
        console.log('confirming payment');
        const {paymentIntent, error} = await confirmPayment(clientSecret, {
          type: 'Card',
          paymentMethodType: 'Card',
          paymentMethodData: {
            billing_details,
            payment_method: subscriptionPaymentMethod,
          },
        });
        console.log('clientSecret', clientSecret);
        console.log('Object', {
          type: 'Card',
          paymentMethodType: 'Card',
          paymentMethodData: {
            billing_details,
            payment_method: subscriptionPaymentMethod,
          },
        });
        console.log('paymentIntent', paymentIntent);
        if (paymentIntent) {
          createUser(
            customerId,
            subscriptionId,
            subscriptionStart,
            subscriptionEnd,
          );
        } else if (error) {
          alert(`Payment Error`);
          setSaving(false);
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      alert(`Payment Error 2 ` + e?.message);
      setSaving(false);
    }
  };
```

Backend Code:

```
router.post("/makePayment", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, name, paymentMethod } = req.body;
    if (email === "" || name === "" || !email || !name || !paymentMethod)
      throw "";

    // making new customer
    const customer = await addNewCustomer(email, name, paymentMethod);

    // making new subscription
    const subscription = await addSubscription(customer?.id);

    // getting stripe secret
    const { error, clientSecret } = await getStripeSecret(
      subscription?.latest_invoice?.payment_intent?.payment_method,
      customer?.id
    );

    // saving data in session
    req.session.customerId = customer?.id;
    req.session.subscriptionId = subscription?.id;

    res
      .send({
        clientSecret,
        error,
        customerId: customer?.id,
        subscriptionId: subscription?.id,
        subscriptionPaymentMethod:
          subscription?.latest_invoice?.payment_intent?.payment_method,
        subscriptionStart: new Date(subscription.current_period_start * 1000),
        subscriptionEnd: new Date(subscription.current_period_end * 1000),
      })
      .status(!error ? 200 : 500);
  } catch (e) {
    res.send({ error: "Internal Server Error" }).status(500);
  }
});
```

Backend Functions:

```
import Stripe from "stripe";
const { STRIPE_SECRET_KEY, STRIPE_API_VERSION } = process?.env;
const stripe = Stripe(STRIPE_SECRET_KEY, { apiVersion: STRIPE_API_VERSION });

export const getStripeSecret = async (paymentMethod, customerId) => {
  try {
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount: 28000, //lowest denomination of particular currency
      currency: "aud",
      payment_method_types: ["card"], //by default
      payment_method: paymentMethod,
      customer: customerId,
    });
    const clientSecret = paymentIntent?.client_secret;

    return { clientSecret };
  } catch (e) {
    return { error: e?.message };
  }
};

export const addNewCustomer = async (email, name, paymentMethod) => {
  try {
    const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
      email,
      description: name,
      payment_method: paymentMethod,
      invoice_settings: {
        default_payment_method: paymentMethod,
      },
    });
    return customer;
  } catch (e) {
    return { error: e?.message };
  }
};

export const addSubscription = async (customerId) => {
  try {
    const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
      customer: customerId,
      items: [{ price: process.env.STRIPE_PRICE_ID }],
      payment_settings: {
        payment_method_options: {
          card: {
            request_three_d_secure: "automatic",
          },
        },
        payment_method_types: ["card"],
        save_default_payment_method: "on_subscription",
      },
      expand: ["latest_invoice.payment_intent"],
    });
    return subscription;
  } catch (e) {
    return { error: e?.message };
  }
};
```

I tried following the above-shared code. I would want to have my subscription active, just like without 3D Secure.

Without 3D secure:
[image: Without 3D secure]

With 3D secure
[image: With 3D secure]

Comment: Hard to say without the full code showing how you actually call the Stripe API (like what the `addSubscription` function does and what the `getStripeSecret` function does). Also why are there two identical payments at the same time? That seems like a potential bug to look into?

Comment: @karllekko, the question is updated, please check. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be creating and using a new PaymentIntent in getStripeSecret. You already have a PaymentIntent — it's the one available in `subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent`. You should be getting and returning the client_secret from that one and using it on the frontend. With your current code you are processing two separate payments(hence the duplicates) and the one you process on the frontend is not connected to the Subscription at all(hence why it remains inactive). You should carefully read and exactly implement the guide at

https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements
But as a start your code should be more like this:

```
// making new subscription
const subscription = await addSubscription(customer?.id); 
// getting stripe secret
const clientSecret = subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent.client_secret;
...
```

Comment: It finally worked! thank you so much for your input. :D